# How does one access the latitude and longitude of a Firestore Geopoint Object with Python (this should be easy!)?

Tags: python, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, properties, geopoints

I am having difficulty retrieving the latitude and longitude from a Firestore Geopoint object in Python.  I've tried multiple ways but none of them seem to work. Any suggestions? The geopoint object is at alertLocation in the dict.

Code:

```py
docs = db.collection(u'users').where(u'first', u'==', u'MyFirstName').stream()

for doc in docs:
    logger.log_text(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Output:

```
HHA5pGRN1rBtGtHRgDS7 => {'alertLocation': <google.cloud.firestore_v1._helpers.GeoPoint object at 0x3e1877599e50>, 'first': 'MyFirstName', 'email': 'me@email.com', 'last': 'mylastname'}
```

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve the object from the dictionary?

Comment: This works, but it doesn't show any part of the object. `code` list_alertLocation = doc.to_dict()["alertLocation"]

Comment: Using doc.to_dict() returns a dictionary of the doc; what you want is access to the GeoPoint object (i.e., you want doc.to_dict()['alertLocation'] ).  The latitude and longitude are stored on the GeoPoint object as properties, which are accessed via dot-notation.  Replacing your format string with `f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()['alertLocation'].latitude}'` will give you the latitude, for example.  The default GeoPoint object representation only gives you the object id (in memory), rather than a pretty representation showing the latitude and longitude.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @KDN :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `doc.to_dict()` returns a dictionary of the doc; what you want is access to the `GeoPoint` object (i.e., you want `doc.to_dict()['alertLocation']` ). The latitude and longitude are stored on the GeoPoint object as properties, which are accessed via dot-notation. Replacing your format string with `f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()['alertLocation'].latitude}'` will give you the latitude, for example. The default `GeoPoint` object representation only gives you the object id (in memory), rather than a pretty representation showing the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my problem was with the logger function I was trying to use and less so with accessing the property in the geopoint object.   I needed to convert the latitude into a string for the log_text method to work correctly.

```
logger.log_text(str(doc.to_dict()["alertLocation"].latitude))
```

Comment: While the use of `str` may improve consistency of behavior in some cases, it shouldn't be necessary here.  The output from your example is printing the object representation (from the object's `__repr__` method), and since the latitude and longitudes are just `float`s, they will be automatically converted to suitable values of strings.  Calling `str()` on these objects ensures that the `__str__` method is called instead of `__repr__`.  However, the behaviors are the same for floats.

Comment: If you want more control over the numerical representation, you could use `f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()['alertLocation'].latitude: 6.2f}`, for example, where the `: +6.2f` indicates a float with 2 decimal places, 6 total spaces wide, padded with spaces, and with a leading + or - sign.  For details, see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html